# Rails Validation of a Group of Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have two objects, Project and User, which are joined by an object called ProjectAssignment. The ProjectAssignments object has an additional field: project_role. Models shown below.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relationships
  has_many :project_assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :project_assignments
end

class ProjectAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project_role
end

class User
  has_many :project_assignments
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_assignments
end
```

I have to validate that for a given project, there is exactly one ProjectAssignment with a project_role of "Principal Investigator" at any time. I'm a little unsure how to write a validation in the ProjectAssignment model. If I unset the current PI first then there is less than 1 Principal Investigator and if set a user to Principal Investigator before unsetting the other there is more than 1.

```
class ProjectAssignment
  validates :allow_exactly_one_pi

  def require_exactly_one_pi  
    if self.project_role.name == 'Principal Investigator' and other_princ_inv_exists
      #more than one principle investigator set => error
    elseif was_principle_investigator
      #no principle investigator set => error
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions how this should be handled?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mentioned that for a given project, there is one projectassignment.  If this is the case, then shouldn't this be a has_one?  Or can a particular project have more than one projectassignment?

Comment: A project can have more than one project assignment, but only one project assignment where project_role is principal investigator.

Comment: I see.  Just to challenge your thinking a bit, perhaps a projectassignment can have many users and belong to one project.  This way the the users in the projectassignment have roles.  Otherwise youre just wrapping each user in their own projectassignment -- is this really what you want?

Comment: But each user can have multiple projects for which they can have different roles. I don't think this can be represented in the model you're describing.

Comment: Sure, a user can belong to many PA's.  A Project can have many PA's (or a single PA if you prefer).  So now just validate that a PA can only have 1 user with the role PI.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice problem to chew on.

First you have to expose something about one model to another,  there is a specific kind of role (principal investigator),  and ProjectAssignment must be aware of that 'special case' role.  But!  it should be the project role that keeps track of that special status,  so I'd add a method to the ProjectRole model:

```
ProjectRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  def ispi?
    self.name == 'Principal Investigator'
  end
end
```

Then you have to figure out how to iterate over all project_asssignments and determine if any of them are a principal investigator.  You have to access a Class method from an instance of a project_assignment.

```
class ProjectAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :there_can_only_be_one_principal_investigator

  def there_can_only_be_one_principal_investigator
    error = false
    self.class.where('project_id = ?',self.project_id).each do |p|
      if p.project_role.ispi?
         error = true
         break
      end
    end
    if error
      #whatever
    end
  end
end
```

Now you have to change your associations,  ProjectAssignment can only have ONE role,  so

```
class ProjectAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :project_role
end
```

So now you are assured you cannot add a ProjectAssignment with project_role == Principal Investigator, if a Principal Investigator already exists for that Project.

What about an update,  you update a ProjectAssignment with the project_role == PI,  and there already is another ProjectAssignment with a PI,  the validation will catch that.

Now how do you assure there is at least ONE PI?  I think what that means is the FIRST ProjectAssignment for any one Project MUST be a PI.  This is where you have to be a little hackish,  you have to expose knowledge about the ProjectRole model directly in the ProjectAssignment model.

```
validate  :there_must_be_at_least_one_principal_investigator

def there_must_be_at_least_one_principal_investigator
  if self.class.where('project_id = ?', self.project_id).count() == 0 AND !self.project_role_id == 1
     #error
  end
end
```

I don't really like this solution,  because the fact that the PI roles's id is 1 (or whatever it is), is hardcoded in another Model!!  To make it a little LESS objectionable, you could add a Class method to the ProjectRole model

```
class ProjectRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.piid
     1 # or whatever it is
  end
end
```

Then do this:

```
def there_must_be_at_least_one_principal_investigator
  if self.class.where('project_id = ?', self.project_id).count() == 0 AND ! self.project_role_id == ProjectRole.piid
     #error
  end
end
```

Now,  how do you change the principal investigator?  You'll have to do that in a seperate action,  i.e.

```
class ProjectAssignmentController < ApplicationController
  def change_pi
     @proj_assignment1 = ProjectAssignment.find(params[:orig_pi_id])
     @proj_assignment2 = ProjectAssignment.find(params[:new_pi_id])
     @proj_assignment1.project_role_id = params[:new_role_for_orig_pi].to_i
     @proj_assignment1.save :validate=>false # it's OK,  you're taking care of it below
     @proj_assignment2.project_role_id = ProjectRole.piid
     @proj_assignment2.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm reading the code wrong but I think this only exemplifies the problem that I'm having. There must be exactly one PI at all times. The code above throws an error when ispi? is true for another project assignment. Additionally I must ensure that there is never no principal investigator assigned to a project. If i enforce both of these rules in the project assignment validation I can never change who the principal investigator is for the project.

Comment: OK, I understand your dilemma a little more clearly now.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: OK, I added to the answer,  but after posting it,  I think the simple answer is that you can't CHANGE the PI,  and only rely on validations,  you'll have to create some UI specifically for changing the PI,  because no matter what you do to change the PI,  at some point the validations will fail.  The last part of the answer is just some example pseudo code,  It should probably be done in the ProjectController, not ProjectAssignment controller,  but I think you'll get the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely different approach,  in summary format:

1) When you Create a new Project,  ask for the User who should be the PI,  and build the first ProjectAssignment record,  that eliminates the need to validate that there is at least one PI.

2) In ProjectController and in your projects edit view,  create a 'change PI' interface of some kind,  in that interface you'd need to know the user_id of the user that becomes the new PI, and the project_role_id that the current PI needs to be assigned if he stays on the project,  if project_role_id is nil,  that means that user should be deleted from the project.

This approach would eliminate validations altogether!

The first answer was a very fun exercise,  and I hate to suggest someone change their entire approach,  I'd rather just answer the question asked the best I can.  But after seeing how complex the 'validations' became,  I think it would be best not to rely on them in your case,  you just have to CODE your app to insure your conditions are met.

HTH